# Update MySQL Table from Subquery/Joined Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've seen many questions along this issue, but can't get this to work.
I want to UPDATE multiple columns in a table (but will start with one) based upon a calculated value from the same table.
It is a list of transactions per customer, per month.

```
TransID | Cust | Month      | Value | PastValue | FutureValue
      1 |    1 | 2018-01-01 |    45 |
      2 |    1 | 2018-02-01 |     0 |  
      3 |    1 | 2018-03-01 |    35 |
      4 |    1 | 2018-04-01 |    80 |
```

.

```
UPDATE tbl_transaction a
SET PrevMnthValue = 
(SELECT COUNT(TransactionID) FROM tbl_transaction b WHERE b.Cust=a.Cust AND b.Month<a.Month)
```

But we get the dreaded 'Can't update a table using a where with a subquery of the same table).

I've tried to nest the subquery as this has been touted as a workaround:

```
UPDATE tbl_transactions a 
SET 
    PastValue = 
        (
            SELECT CNT FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    COUNT(TransactionID) AS CNT
                    FROM tbl_transactions b
                    WHERE
                        b.CustomerRef=a.CustomerRef AND b.Month<a.Month
                ) x
        ),
    FutureValue = 
        (
            SELECT CNT FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                    COUNT(TransactionID) AS CNT
                    FROM tbl_transactions b
                    WHERE
                        b.CustomerRef=a.CustomerRef AND b.Month>a.Month
                ) x
        )
```

But I get an UNKNOWN a.CustomerRef in WHERE clause.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: table aliases in MySQL only go down one nesting level you have two nesting levels so you need to join the table tbl_transactions  again where you count.. If you can't work it out with mine advice i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide example data and expected results.. Maybe you should provide example data  annyway because a co-related subquery possibly isn't the best optimized query method to get the answer.

Comment: Don't store derived data

Comment: Why not @Strawberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update and read from one table at the same time. 
MySQL documentation tell about it

> [You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

At first you must select necessary data and save them to somewhere, for example to [temporary table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` AS (
   SELECT 
     COUNT(`TransactionID`) AS CNT,
     `CustomerRef`,
     `Month`
   FROM `tbl_transactions`
   GROUP BY `Custom,erRef`, `Month`
);
```

After it, you can use JOIN statement for update table

```
UPDATE `tbl_transactions` RIGTH
JOIN `temp` ON `temp`.`CustomerRef` = `tbl_transactions`.`CustomerRef`
AND `temp`.`Month` < `tbl_transactions`.`Month`
SET `tbl_transactions`.`PastValue` = `temp`.`cnt`
```

**UPDATED:** if you want to update several columns by different condition you can combine temporary table, UPDATE + RIGHT JOIN and [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) statement. For example:

```
UPDATE `tbl_transactions`
RIGTH JOIN `temp` ON `temp`.`CustomerRef` = `tbl_transactions`.`CustomerRef` 
SET `tbl_transactions`.`PastValue` = CASE
    WHEN `temp`.`Month` < `tbl_transactions`.`Month` THEN `temp`.`cnt`
    ELSE `tbl_transactions`.`PastValue`
END, 
`tbl_transactions`.`FutureValue` = CASE
    WHEN `temp`.`Month` > `tbl_transactions`.`Month` THEN `temp`.`cnt`
    ELSE `tbl_transactions`.`FutureValue`
END
```

Comment: I've updated the question, there is actually more than one field to be updated with different subquery criteria from the same table.  You can't reference a temporary table more than once in the same query.  I've created a duplicate table for now.  Would be nice to understand how to use the join in my Scenario.  I'm using my query I posted, but referencing the physical 'temp' table.

Comment: @aSystemOverload I updated my answer in compliance with new information in the question

Comment: Whilst this hasn't solved my specific problem.  My question is substantially simplified, it has put me on the right path and this does solve the simplified version, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
UPDATE tbl_transactions a 
Join
( SELECT CustomerRef,COUNT(TransactionID) AS CNT FROM tbl_transactions b 
group by CustomerRef)x
SET PastValue = CNT 
WHERE x.CustomerRef=a.CustomerRef AND x.Month<a.Month
```

Comment: I've updated the question, there is actually more than one field to be updated with different subquery criteria from the same table.  How would that work?